# Facebook SDK import error

Tags: java, android, facebook, maven, android-studio

I got a issue when I try to import FB SDK into my project.

Here is a log after I execute project clean.

```
>Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'XXX'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.

   > Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/OOO/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository
/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.pom
         file:/Users/OOO/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository
/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar
         file:/Users/OOO/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository
/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.pom
         file:/Users/OOO/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository
/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         :XXX:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook:4.6.0
```

And here is my import step

1) import moudule

2) add dependdencies :facebook

3) modify gradle.properties as below

```
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION = 23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = 23.0.1
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 15
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION =2
```

seems doesn't work... It there any way to resolve that?

My build.gradle file:

```
{
apply plugin: 'android'
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
compile files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')
compile project(':facebook')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this dependency in your `builld.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
```

remove this or your `module` as a library which you have added for Facebook SDK

```
compile project(':facebook')
```

Comment: still error... Could not find com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0.  :(

Comment: I think you have updated wrong build.gradle file!, you should change modeule:app one's gradle not Project: yourProjectName, try doing this or share your all gradle files along with Project structure screenshot from your android studio! so I can help you out more about this.

Comment: I found another solution. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way for this issue.  I create a libs folder under my project facebook folder . then put bolts-android:1.2.0.jar into libs folder.

and modify build.gradle under my project facebook folder. it seems work.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
}
```